# iOS: integrate a Framework containing pods

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods

I created a framework 'MyFramework' that contains a pod lib1 that contains also pod lib2. When I add it to my project and run, I get this error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/lib2 reference from /Users/User/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/158294F9-11AD-451C-9585-A3F0BAF66DE7/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2CDBC90C-DF18-4528-91DF-D90DC9A239C3/MyTestProject.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework Reason: image not found
```

How a Framework work if it has a pod that contain a pod...
Why I get this ? is there something to do like in android (set transitive to true in the dependency) ? I just want to understand.

Or should I create third party library of MyFramework and add it as a pod ?

Comment: check your framework is added in embeded framework

Comment: Yes of cours.. MyFramework works perfectly without the pod. when I add the pod to the framework I get that error... 
(ps: the pod contains another pod..)

Comment: So is there any help please ?